# Foul language on profile info

Tags: feature-request, censor

I see no foul language on comments, answers or questions, but what about profile info?

Is foul language allowed there? Check out this [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3490850/hackerman)

Comment: I guess you haven't seen [Welbog's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog) profile yet... :)

Comment: Fundamental difference, @BlueIce, between the two. Other than one's fun to read.